# ReportViewer not displaying after converting rdlc to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I have a report rdlc which I just migrate from vs 2010 to vs 2012, I'm using a method to convert the rdlc file to an pdf file and sending the report by email.

The email is being sent successfully but the report is throwing this error : "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto".

I guess that something happened when I convert the rdlc file to pdf and then the report can´t be read.

This is the method I use to convert rdlc to pdf.

```
private string ExportReportToPDF(string reportName)
    {
        try
        {
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string filenameExtension;
            byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
               "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                out streamids, out warnings);

            string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), reportName)+".pdf";
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }

            return filename;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
           // Throws error
        }

    }
```

After that I just add the file to the mail and send it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found out that the reportviewer change its format (or losses references, or it´s already initiallize) when I run the following code:

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
               "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                out streamids, out warnings);

Is there another way to convert rdlc to pdf without using render method?

Comment: You can look into iTextSharp as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but something was making the reportviewer to not render properly after obtaining the bytes to convert to pdf.

After trying different ways to solve I found out that I just needed to refresh my reportviewer again so after calling the ExportToPDF method and sending the mail I just added the following line:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```